# Error when using django formset

Tags: python, django

I need to clone form as many times as i want. My goal is: user choose how many stocks he needs then redirect to page with same number of forms (probably i shoud use something like Ajax but for now its too hard for me). Found out that i should use `formset`. For now i have error `ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with`

Using `django-datetime-widget` and `django-crispy-forms`

`forms.py` :

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import *
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import *
from datetimewidget.widgets import DateWidget

class InputDates(forms.Form): 
    Date_start = forms.DateField(widget=DateWidget(
        # attrs={'id':"datetimeid1"},
        usel10n = True,
        bootstrap_version=3
    ),
        label='first date',
        required=True,
    )

    Date_end = forms.DateField(widget=DateWidget(
            # attrs={'id':"datetimeid2"},
            usel10n = True,
            bootstrap_version=3
        ),
        label='last date',
        required=True,
    )

    Stock = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=(   ('GG', 'Google'),
                    ('APPL', 'Apple'),
                    ('SR', 'Smth1'),
                    ('GZ', 'Smth2'),),
        required=True,
        label='Choose your stock'
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InputDates, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('Stock'),
            Field('Date_start'),
            Field('Date_end'),
        )

class BTN(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BTN, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Make graph', css_class='btn btn-default')
            ),
        )
```

`views.py` :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

def stocks(request):
    btn = BTN(request.POST or None)
    StocksFormset = formset_factory(InputDates, extra=2)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = StocksFormset(request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'home.html')

    else:
        formset = StocksFormset()

    return render(request, 'stocks.html', {'formset' : formset, 'BTN' : btn})
```

`stocks.html` :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post" class="text-left">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
          {% crispy form form.helper %} 
    {% endfor %}
</form>
    {% crispy BTN BTN.helper %}

{% endblock %}
```

In `Django` docs for `formset` i found i should use `{{ formset.management_form }}` and everything will be fine, but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the way you are trying to render the formset forms using crispy forms.

Specifically you need to set `form_tag` to `False` in the helper, as currently it will be rendering a separate `<form>` tag for each form in the set, which will thoroughly confuse the browser:

```
class InputDates(forms.Form):
    # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InputDates, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
```

You also need to set `form_tag` to `False` on the `BTN` form helper given that you are manually rendering the `<form>` tag.

Here's the [relevant part of the documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_formsets.html#formset-forms-with-different-layouts):

> In your view you will need to change the layout or use a different help for every formset’s form. Make sure that you have `form_tag` attribute set to `False`, otherwise you will get 3 individual forms rendered.